# What does the current signal look like just south of Las Vegas?

Tags: repeater, range

I was wondering if it would be worth it to engage some of the hotels south of the strip to see if they would allow us to put a repeater on one of the buildings there.  Just wondering as the Marriott, Caesars Palace and New York New York block the repeaters installed north of the strip.   Basically, what does the signal quality look like south of the strip?  I may have a hotel that would consider putting up a repeater if the community provides enough feedback for it.

Comment: This question is relevant only to a small geographical area, at a specific time.

Comment: This question also lacks context. Which signal?

Answer (score 0):

Because your question is about information for such a small geographical area, I would suggest contacting one of these organizations:

- [Las Vegas Radio Amateur Club](http://www.lvrac.org/index.html)
- [Las Vegas Repeater Association (LVRA)](http://www.hxo.com/)
- [NARRI - NEVADA AMATEUR RADIO REPEATERS, INC](http://www.narri.org/)

You could also join the [Las Vegas HAM Radio Reflector Yahoo Group](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/lvrac/info) and ask your question there.